# Memory Limits for SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard and Analysis Services

Tags: sql-server, memory-management, sql-server-2008-r2, licensing, server-configuration

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143685%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), the memory limit for SQL Server 2008 Standard edition is 64 GB.  Does anyone know if this total is for SQL Server only, for each service you run on that instance (SQL, SSAS, SSIS), or a single total that is shared among all services you run within that instance.

For example, if I want to allocate 64 GB of memory to SQL, will there be any memory available **under my license** for me to run any other services on that instance?

**Note:** This is not a question about physical memory limitations, as my server has more than enough physical memory to meet my allocation requirements.  I am only curious to know if I will be limited by the license itself.

Comment: Each SqlServer instance itself is eager in allocationg memory. Your other process will get swapped to disk (and back-into memory when they are scheduled by the os scheduler). Just wondering: you have a server with 64GB ram available?

Comment: @rene put it as answer. Btw., 64gb is quite small these days. I would not even call that a "mid range" serve. I am just buying a small server with that.

Comment: @rene Yes, the server itself has plenty of physical memory.  I would have no trouble allocating 64 Physical GB to both SQL and SSAS, providing I am not limited by an arbitrary licensing constraint.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Comment: @JasonMArcher The question is actually more about features of a specific edition of SQL Server.  This is not a question asking about legal advice, or containing any gray areas of what kind of licencing is appropriate for my software.  I'll admit that the use of the term licence here makes that less clear, but in this case its just another way of labelling a software product (Like Windows Home vs Professional)

Comment: It is a question about the limitations of your licensing agreement with Microsoft, therefore it is off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's 64GB limit is per instance, not server. Other people were asking the same question in this article... http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/sql-server-r-standard-supports-less-memory/

Comment: Maybe, but that article only talks about multiple instances of SQL server, each of which would require its own license.  It's not entirely clear how it would apply to instances of different services running under a single license (e.g, 1 instance of SQL and 1 instance of AS, which would only require a total of 1 license)